# Is it possible to have a stateless server with token based authentication that is not vulnerable to replay attacks?

Tags: authentication, token

Currently I have a server that makes use of JSON Web Tokens in order to manage user authentication.
When a user submits a valid authentication request, they receive a JWT which contains information such as their user ID that allows the server to process authentication sensitive requests.

The plain text body of the JWT will take a form similar to:

```
{  
    "UserID":"100",  
    "Expires":"(expiryDate)",  
    "IssuedBy":"ServerOne"    
}
```

However, as you could quite correctly point out, this does not afford us any way to validate that the agent presenting the access token is in fact the user who it was originally issued to.
As such, if someone were able to obtain the JWT, then assuming it has not expired they would be able to assume the user's identity and gain unauthorised access.

A stateless server is a must for the current project, so I would struggle to use a solution which involves the server keeping track of logged in users.
Is it possible to achieve security using Tokens in this manner?

I've done a bit of reading on the topic, and I remember someone suggesting to use something like the "X-Forwarded-For" header and placing the user's IP in the token then comparing the two, but that has it's own drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of specs in the OAuth 2.0 / JWT space right now, which try to address this problem. Take a look at [RFC 7800](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800) and [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-binding-03).

There are several commercial Authorization Servers / Identity Providers out there which already support RFC 7800 and a couple of open source implementations as well.